# ArcGIS Server Image Service from Mosaic Layer

Tags: arcgis-server, imagery, arcgis-image-server

I have successfully created an image service from a mosaic dataset using NAIP imagery. I would like to create another image service that displays the same area in NIR (4,3,2). I have created a mosaic layer with the display using 4,3,2 and I was able to use the layer to create a new image service.(pointing to the same mosaic dataset) But the new image service does not display in NIR. I have also tried generating tile cache from the NIR mosaic layer and copying to the server, and it still does not display.

If I add the mosaic layer into arcmap, and open the attribute table for the mosaic dataset and select to view individual rasters, they do display in NIR.

The point of me doing this is so I can display my imagery in different ways, while referencing the same image files, to save space.

Has anyone successfully accomplished this?

Comment: Try publishing the layer as an image service and then set different functions to render the data differently. ESRI has a free online class on this.